# Drupal create custom content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-content-types

I am very new to drupal. I am creating cars website using drupal.

Need to create cars model content type.

Please look example site http://automobiles.honda.com/all-models.aspx

Cars have many models and it each model has many features page like http://automobiles.honda.com/accord-coupe/

http://automobiles.honda.com/accord-coupe/price.aspx

http://automobiles.honda.com/accord-coupe/specifications.aspx

I don't know how to create a content type for this type requirement.

Can I do like this in drupal?

Is there any related modules available for this requirement?

Please give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the in-built content type creation interface. Go to struture > content type and add new content type along with the fields you need.
Also, before you start building the site, learn more about Drupal. This will help you a lot!